# How to implement tabs with AngularJS stateProvider and ui-view?

Tags: angularjs, uiview, angularjs-directive, tabs, angular-ui-router

Hi I have created a simple application that lets you create a new post and see existing posts.

However I am now trying to have tabs with my application. Meaning there is a separate tab for adding a new post, and a separate tab for seeing existing posts. So there should be two tabs. One for adding new post, one for seeing existing ones.

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>App</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!--External Javascript, uses Angular 1.3+ Framework-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="post.js"></script>
  </head>
  <!-- 
  Body
  -->
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- 
For angular routing
Home/Main page 
-->
<script type = "text/ng-template" id = "/main.html">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Post Center</h1>
    </div>

    <form id = "form" ng-submit="addForm()">
      <h3>New post</h3>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Title"></input>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Name"></input>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
    </form>

    <h3>Existing posts</h3>

    <div ng-repeat="post in posts">

      <span style="color: navy; font-size:15px; text-align: left; display: block;">
        <b>Title</b>:  {{post.Title}}&nbsp&nbsp
        <b>Name</b>:  {{post.Name}}&nbsp&nbsp
      </span>

      <span>
        <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
      </span>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </script>

  <!-- 
  Comments on a particular post
   -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h4>
        <br>
        <b>Title</b>:  {{post.Title}}
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">
      {{comment.author}}

      <span id= "comment">
        {{comment.body}}
      </span>
    </div>

    <form ng-submit="addComment()">
      <h3> New Comment </h3>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <input type = "text" class = "form-control" ng-model = "body"></input>
      </div>
      <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Add</button>
    </form>
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my post.js file:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
// Angular Routing
$stateProvider.state('main', {
    url: '/main',
    templateUrl: '/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
}).state('posts', {
    url: '/posts/{id}',
    templateUrl: '/posts.html',
    controller: 'PostCtrl'
});

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('main');

}]);

app.factory('posts', [function(){
var o = {
    posts: [
        {Title: "Example post 1", Name: 'Bobby', comments: []},
        {Title: "Example post 2", Name: 'Jason', comments: []},
        {Title: "Example post 3", Name: 'Newton', comments: []},
      ]
};
return o;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'posts', function($scope, posts){

  $scope.posts = posts.posts;

  // To add new post
  $scope.addForm = function() {
    $scope.posts.push({
    Title: $scope.Title, 
    Name: $scope.Name,
    comments: []
  });

// After adding new post, set the fields to blank again
$scope.Title = '';
$scope.Name = '';
 };
}]);

app.controller('PostCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'posts', function($scope, $stateParams, posts){

$scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];

// To add new comment to post
$scope.addComment = function(){
    if ($scope.body === ''){
        return;
    };

    $scope.post.comments.push({
        body: $scope.body,
        author: 'Person',
    });

    $scope.body = '';
}
}]);
```

I have tried a lot of different options and got no good result. For example I have tried using a tabset (does not work because my main.html is in  tag), panes, and even regular nav bar (does not work because navigation messes up the ui-router.

Please help me solve this puzzle! Thank you!!

Comment: can u share a plunk?

Comment: Yep, here is the updated plunker with everything so far: http://plnkr.co/edit/3HVgE4vq8Z10HBRgzDfv?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

if it's possible for you to add ui-bootstrap to your project, then you could use it along with uirouter with ease.

here's an example of tabs, using nested routes.
note that all nested routes inherit from main route's controller, as seen in their templates.

configure routes on controller's scope:

```
$scope.tabs = [
  { title:'Posts', route: 'home.posts' },
  { title:'addPost', route: 'home.addPost' }
];

$scope.go = function(route) {
  $state.go(route);
};
```

stateProvider:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl'
}).state('home.posts', {
    url: 'home/posts/{id}',
    templateUrl: 'posts.html'
}).state('home.addPost', {
    url: 'home/addPost',
    templateUrl: 'addPost.html'
});

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
```

index.html:

```
<tabset>
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" select="go(tab.route)" ui-sref-active="tab.active" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/dYuXfcMLe7JEg8wVoPkE?p=preview

Comment: I noticed you put the following in home.html in the plunker instead of index.html. Is that how it's supposed to be?<tabset>
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" select="go(tab.route)" ui-sref-active="tab.active" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </tab>
</tabset>

Comment: Here is the updated plunker with everything so far: http://plnkr.co/edit/3HVgE4vq8Z10HBRgzDfv?p=preview

Comment: axc, here's a working plnkr. you had some typos in the routes configuration. http://plnkr.co/edit/pLizuyS6BVpaABUvE111?p=preview

Comment: Thank you @Nitsan Baleli for the help, however I don't see how this is working because I cannot add a post or see posts?

Comment: @axc no problem. keep in mind that an answer can give you a direction, but you will have to do all the hard work yourself. good luck

Comment: @NitsanBaleli And does it store the states? i mean the views data/state are persistent or not?